# No module named pysqlite2._sqlite Error with flask

Tags: python, flask, pysqlite

Hi I m have a problem with No module named pysqlite2._sqlite error

I m using SQLalchemy with flask and virtualenv

when i  query by model like this

```
user  = User.query.filter_by(social_id = social_id).first()
```

i got the following error

```
No module named pysqlite2._sqlite
```

First error was

```
No module named pysqlite2
```

So i install the pysqlite by pip install pysqlite

I try to reinstall the pysqlite by

```
pip uninsatll pysqlite
pip install pysqlite
```

But the same problem is ouccuring

And i check the sqlahcemy code, it import module like this

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2
```

But at the console

from pysqlite2 import dbapi2

is working.

So i check the pysqlite2 library folder

I found that there is _sqlite.so file.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem

Error occur from the google app engine environment

**Google app engine doesn't provide c compiled library.**

sqlite has c complied file, so it can't import module