# ImportError: No module named pysqlite2 --- SQLAlchemy with flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database
and that guy says I should make a script to create the db:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

but when I try to run that script, I get:

```
/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./db_create.py", line 7, in <module>
    db.create_all()
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 972, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 964, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 910, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 545, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 75, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/devuser/wapp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 339, in dbapi
    raise e
ImportError: No module named pysqlite2
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281825/python-sqlalchemy-importerror-no-module-named-pysqlite2) Stackoverflow post doesn't work. Neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044548/importerror-no-module-named-pysqlite2)

When I try to install pysqlite as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292050/no-module-named-pysqlite2-sqlite-error-with-flask) post says (with pip install pysqlite) I get:

```
Collecting pysqlite
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached pysqlite-2.8.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Only Python 2.7 is supported.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JoH01e/pysqlite
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: apt-get install python-dev?

Comment: pip install pysqlite - works fine on OS X.

Comment: already tried pip install pysqlite  ... doesn't work (RedHat) ... see the error above for the pysqlite install

Comment: can you try this - pip install --upgrade setuptools ?

Comment: yes, and I get the following err: http://pastebin.com/jNQfxftv

Comment: should I reinstall pip?

Comment: Please look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error Not sure this will work for Red Hat directly, but maybe it will give you an idea. As I understand, you problem is exactly with setuptools. Maybe if you reinstall pip this will help you.

Comment: You are trying to install pysqlite using Python 2.6. It's setup.py raises an exception for all versions of Python other than 2.7. You need to make sure you're using the correct pip. `python -m pip install pysqlite`